# Lambda invoke Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I can't seem to get this to work. I create 2 lambdas via C9. I'm using boto3 to invoke one lambda from another. Everything seems to work just fine via C9 but when I publish and try to access via API Gateway I keep getting "Endpoint request timed out" errors.

I know it can't be a timeout issue because I've set up my yaml files to have enough time to execute and the lambda right now are really simple (only returning a string)

here are my current yaml file. I'm wondering if maybe there are some sort of permissions I need to include for API Gateway in the second yaml

Lambda1

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
    api:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
        Description: ''
        Handler: api/lambda_function.lambda_handler
        MemorySize: 256
        Role: 'arn:aws:iam::820788395625:role/service-role/api_int-role'
        Runtime: python3.6
        Timeout: 30
        VpcConfig:
            SecurityGroupIds:
                - ...
            SubnetIds:
                - ...
        Policies: AWSLambdaFullAccess
```

Lambda2

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
    api:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
            Description: ''
            Handler: api/lambda_function.lambda_handler
            MemorySize: 512
            Role: 'arn:aws:iam::820788395625:role/service-role/api_int-role'
            Runtime: python3.6
            Timeout: 15
            VpcConfig:
                SecurityGroupIds:
                    - ...
                SubnetIds:
                    - ...
```

I just set up an API Gateway endpoint directly to Lambda2 and it returned no problem. So...

API Gateway -> Lambda 2 (works)
API Gateway -> Lambda 1 -> Lambda 2 (does not work)

So for some reason when I want to call Lambda 2 via Lambda 1 over API Gateway it doesn't work.

Here is the code that is calling the 2nd Lambda

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('call boto3 client')
    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='us-east-1')
    print('boto3 client called')

    print('invoke lambda')
    env_response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='cloud9-apiAlpha-api-TBSOYXLVBCLX',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(event)
    )
    print('lambda invoked')

    print('env_response')
    print(env_response)
    print(env_response['Payload'])
    print(env_response['Payload'].read())

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': 'HELLO WORLD!',
        'isBase64Encoded': False
    }
```

Now when I look at the logs it gets to print('invoke lambda') but then stops and timesout

Comment: does your role have the proper permission  to execute another lambda ? `api_int-role`

Comment: Can you show us the actual code of how are you calling the lambda?

Comment: @AminAhmedKhan I've been told that role has permissions to execute another lambda

Comment: @yorodm I've shared the code calling the 2nd Lambda

Comment: If you're having timeout issues then you either call the lambda asynchronously or increase the timeout threshold of your calling lambda

Comment: @yorodm so when I test via C9 everything returns no problem which leads me to believe Its timing out due to permissions or something because when i try to run via API Gateway it gets to the invoke portion it stops there until it times out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. The answer to my particular problem was Lambda 1 & Lambda 2 were operating over VPC thus no internet connection. Once I removed VPC from Lambda 1 the invocation of Lambda 2 worked without any problems.

Just wanted to share in case I can save anyone else a weeks worth of debugging LOL

Answer (score 1):

1.Invoking a Lambda from another Lambda can't be done without some configuration. In your .yml file, permission must be specified in order to invoke another Lambda. This can be accomplished by adding an iamRoleStatements section under the provider property
 `or` 
by add the simple policy `AWSLambdaRole` to the existing role attached to the lambda `function_1`.

```
provider:  
    name: aws
    runtime: <runtime goes here> # e.g. python3.6 or nodejs6.10
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - lambda:InvokeFunction
        Resource: "*"
```

`or do this add/attach this policy to your existing role attached to your lambda function_1`
[image: AWSLambdaRole]

2.Invoking `lambda function_1` code attached.

```
global LAMBDA_CLIENT
if not LAMBDA_CLIENT:
    LAMBDA_CLIENT = boto3.client('lambda')
try:
    encoded_payload = json.dumps({'message': 'this is an invokcation call form lambda_1'}).encode(UTF_8)

    invoke_resp = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='function_2',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=encoded_payload)

    status_code = invoke_resp['StatusCode']
    if status_code != 200:
        LOGGER.error('error ')
    paylaod = invoke_resp['Payload'].read()
    resp = json.loads(payload)
    print(resp)
except Exception:
```

IF you are using InvocationType=RequestResponse then you can return some response form function_2.

Comment: I created this in C9 and there is a template.yml do I need a serverless.yml also then?

Comment: I think you have a existing role attached to your lambda then its worth attaching this policy AWSLambdaRole to it. So you don't need any changes to  .yml file in your case, apologies if i am not able to explain stuff properly

Comment: There has to be a permissions thing somewhere because in the logs it gets to the invoke_resp = lambda_client.invoke and then hangs and eventually times out

Comment: Ok so it looks like doing this made it work Payload=bytes(encoded_payload)

Comment: nice one `json.loads()` should do it then

Comment: so it looks like the bytes stuff may have been working because it was causing it to fail thus proceeding to my return
unlike without the bytes method it was causing a timeout

Comment: when I run Lambda Remote in C9 I get this error

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)`

Comment: Finally found the solution. Lambda 1 & Lambda 2 were operating over VPC thus no internet connection. Once I removed VPC from Lambda 1 the invocation of Lambda 2 worked without any problems

Comment: @Banning so are you saying that if you have lambdas in a VPC then calling from one to another (even async) is not possible?

Comment: Man this was a saviour. Thanks a lot.